# Javascript - How to get app version/details in play store through api

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

Hello I would like to get the version of my app in the play store using javascript, I'm using it as a reference to get updates with users when they are already outdated with the app. Like iOS there is api link to get details from your app through bundle id

http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=yourbundleid

now I would like to do the same on android but i cant seem to find any proper api which came from android itself.

Any idea where to look? thanks

Comment: This isn't a question for Stack Overflow - you're better off searching Google Apis.

Comment: there is no such API in google as I know.